# what will be correct MySql query?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am performing the following query having some syntax error:

```
SELECT count (tbl_staff.staff_id as staff_number),SELECT count (tbl_client.client_id as client_number),SELECT count (tbl_appointment.appt_id             as appt_number),SELECT count (tbl_subscription.subscription_id as subscription_number)
FROM      tbl_subscription 
LEFT JOIN tbl_staff 
ON        ( 
                tbl_staff.merchant_id = tbl_subscription.merchant_id) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_appointment 
ON        ( 
                tbl_appointment.merchant_id = tbl_subscription.merchant_id) 
LEFT JOIN tbl_client 
ON        ( 
                tbl_client.merchant_id = tbl_subscription.merchant_id) 
WHERE     tbl_subscription.subscription_id=1;
```

I want get the count of staff_id, client_d, appointment_id on particular Subscription_id.

Comment: 1. you don't tell us what the error message is 2. you can't have two SELECT statements in one query

Comment: 1. Remove all of the `SELECT` keywords except the very first one. (You have four.) 2. Move all of the `as ` portions to outside the right parenthesis, like `count(tbl_subscription.subscriptionid) as subscription_number`. 3. Find a SQL tutorial and do some reading. 4. Learn immediately that when you write *an error* you need to be **specific** about the error, including providing the exact error message you're getting. A **syntax error** includes a textual error that contains information about where the error is located. Include that message for us as well.

Comment: @JohnConde I have mentioned that I am having syntax error and I don't know where and  how to do count from different table columns and resulting in one table

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you so much, I will definitely do reading part.and Will take care of all points you have told to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select list is close, but has a few mistakes. Namely, you only need a single SELECT in your query (not one per field) and the "as ..." descriptor belongs outside the parenthesis.

So this part of the query

```
SELECT count (tbl_staff.staff_id as staff_number),
SELECT count (tbl_client.client_id as client_number),
SELECT count (tbl_appointment.appt_id as appt_number),
SELECT count (tbl_subscription.subscription_id as subscription_number)
FROM      tbl_subscription
```

would become

```
SELECT count (tbl_staff.staff_id) as staff_number,
       count (tbl_client.client_id) as client_number,
       count (tbl_appointment.appt_id) as appt_number,
       count (tbl_subscription.subscription_id) as subscription_number
FROM      tbl_subscription
```

Comment: After doing this I am getting Sql Error (1370)